# Password strength control for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, controls

I need a Password strength control for ASP.NET. I looked at control in ajax control toolkit, but it isn't fully configurable. I need to place it statically on the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using googles
Google Password Strength API
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/GooglePasswordStrength.aspx

Comment: That page links to a google api which doesn't appear to be working (for me anyway): https://www.google.com/accounts/RatePassword?Passwd=

Answer (score -1):

Try below validators :

Webforms

[Password Policy/Strength ASP .NET Validator Web Control](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9935e/3981/Default.aspx?ArticleID=4863c712-ed8b-478a-8fbf-13a42d26a04c)

Answer (score -1):

Validator :

MVC

[Password Policy/Strength ASP.NET MVC Validator](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9935e/4405/Default.aspx?ArticleID=94b03c6c-5fd9-4e7e-befd-0624382bd7af)

Answer (score -1):

[AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Default.aspx) actually has a [decent one](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PasswordStrength/PasswordStrength.aspx) if still using web forms.  The bar indicator isn't bad at all.